# Make criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction()) sql injection proof

Tags: sql, hibernate

Folks,

I am building a criteria in hibernate 3 as below. Is this sql injection proof?

```
criteria
    .add(
         Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
            "to_char(createDate,'mm/dd/yyyy') like '%" + dateString + "%'"),
         StandardBasicTypes.STRING);
```

The other option I was thinking was convert the dateString to a date and to this

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(createDate, dateObjCreatedFromString)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not SQL Injection proof, since you are using normal String manipulation to build the restriction. Here's how to do it correctly (given that you have to use sqlRestriction to solve this):

```
criteria
    .add(
         Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
            "to_char(createDate,'mm/dd/yyyy') like ?", 
            "%" + dateString + "%", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would parse the date string into a java date. It also has the advantage that you have better control of the supported date format.

It would be even better when the string is converted by the client. The client can handle wrongly formatted input strings better.